# Automorphisms of cospectral k-regular graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

In the end of chapter $5$ of the book Spectra of Graphs of Cvetkovic, Doob, and Sachs, it is stated that for any pair of finite groups $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, there is a pair of cospectral graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, whose automorphism groups are the groups mentioned.

From this statement, one can understand that there is little or no relation between the spectrum and automorphism group of graphs.

**Question:** If we restrict ourselves to cospectral $k$-regular graphs, can we compare their automorphism groups in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Mendelsohn proved that every finite group is the automorphism group of a Steiner triple system. The block graph of a Steiner triple system is strongly regular and its parameters are determined by the number of points of the system, hence the block graphs of Steiner triple systems on $v$ points are all cospectral. It is also known that almost all Steiner triple systems are asymmetric.

So assuming more regularity does not help in getting a useful correlation between spectrum and automorphism group.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!
I was hoping there was a relation between the spectrum of the edge adjacency matrix and the automorphism group. But this shows otherwise.